# Need recommendations for Graphql resolvers structure

Tags: graphql

I am trying to make structure for GraphQl resolvers, but a bit stuck.

Imagine that we have different sale type entities

```
type Sale {
   name: String
   value: Float
   type: Int
}
```

Currently we have a query which gets all the sales by type and compare them for different date ranges

```
type SaleResult {
   name: String
   main_value: Float
   compare_value: Float
   difference: Float
   type: Int
}

input DateParamsInput {
   start: DateTime!
   end: DateTime!
}

input SomeFilterInput {
   dateRangeMain: DateParamsInput
   dateRangeCompare: DateParamsInput
   type: [Int]
}

Query {
 getSales(filter: SomeFilterInput) [SaleResult]
}
```

and now we were requested to add a switcher to grab data either without compare value or with it. We can add new query but I am trying to find a way to have single query for both cases

There is a solution, how I see it

```
Query {
   getSales2(type: [Int]) {
     sale {
        name
        type
        diff(mainRange, compareRange) {
           main_value
           compare_value
           diff
        }
        value(mainRange)
      }
   }
}
```

In this case we will have 2 nested resolvers: `diff` and `value`. The first one can return data with compare value and another one for single value

Another way

```
Query {
   getSales2(type: [Int], mainRange) {
     sale {
        name
        type
        value
        compare(compareRange) {
           value
           diff
        }
      }
   }
}
```

but in this case we have to have value before compare resolver starts and I am not sure this is the working approach

Since I have no one to validate this, I am asking for your help. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: How about simply not populating `compare_value` and `difference` from the existing `SaleResult` type if you did not receive any `dateRangeCompare` input?

Comment: Do you mean having two filter attributes: mainRange and compareRange? I think this approach is not extendable, don't you? But that's will definitely work